# Angular moment (Hibbeler's book question)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, physics

This question's from the book HIBBELER, R. **Engineering Mechanics: Statics**; chapter 4.

The curved rod lies in the x-y plane and has radius $3m$. If a force $F=80N$ acts at its end as shown, determine the moment of this force about point B.
[image]

The answer is $M_B = \{-37,6i+ 90,7j -155k\}N.m$

I can't make it to the right answer. I got $M_B=\{-37,6i+37,6j-75,1k\}N.m$

Please, I'll be grateful if someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: @MSEisadatingsite well, can you help me?